# How to find DIV inside div-structure by InnerText or Class

Tags: javascript, html, find, selector, evaluate

I have a div with multiple children which have a large div structure in them. Now I want to find an element with an specific innerText.
How can I do this?
I have heard something from document.evaluate but is this the right thing?

```html
<div className="main">
  <div className="child1">
    <div>
      <div><label className="text1">First Label</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="child2">
    <div>
      <div><label className="text2">Second Label</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="child3">
    <div>
      <div><label className="text3">Third Label</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have main and want to find the Label with the text Second Label without multiple Loops.

Comment: This looks like JSX, not proper HTML (because of the `className` "attributes"). And have you considered *not using DIVs* ? The semantics in your example are either wrong (labels unattached to an input) or non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

Using an XPath expression in Javascript  you can query for the specific element and use `text()` to query the text within the element.

```js
const getnodes = function(expr, parent) {
  let results = [];
  let contextNode = parent || document;
  let query = document.evaluate(expr, contextNode, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  for (let i = 0, length = query.snapshotLength; i < length; ++i) {
    results.push(query.snapshotItem(i));
  }
  return results;
};


let col = getnodes('//div[@class="main"]//label/text()[ contains(.,"Second Label") ]');
col.forEach(n => {
  console.log(n.textContent)
});


let ref=document.querySelector('div.main > div.child3');

col=getnodes('div/div/label',ref);
col.forEach(n => {
  console.log('Using explicit reference node:',n.textContent)
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child1">
    <div>
      <div><label class="text1">First Label</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div>
      <div><label class="text2">Second Label</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <div>
      <div><label class="text3">Third Label</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I can just set the ContextNode from document to the div in which I want to search?

Comment: if you have a reference node then you can use that as the basis for the query as the contextnode yes

Comment: Sorry, but when I use a querySelector instead of document in ContextNode, It's also searching in the whole document.

Comment: it depends how specific the query is in relation to the contextnode

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use path search. For more information on this check [Document evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

```
var xPath = "//label[contains(text(),'First Label')]";
console.log(document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue);
```

Comment: OK, but can I set anywhere the main div in which it should search? Like the div with class="main" in my question.

Comment: Just change the search node in the case of this example the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a `document.querySelectorAll ("label")`

```
const len = document.querySelectorAll("label");

for (let i = 1; i < len.length+1; i++) {
  var el = document.querySelector("label[classname=text"+i+"]");
  console.log(el.innerText);
  if(el.innerText == "First Label") {
    console.log("Found!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
  "//label[contains(text(),'Second Label')]", // xpathExpression
  document.querySelector(".main"), // contextNode
  null, // namespaceResolver
  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, // resultType
  null // result
).iterateNext();
console.log(xpathResult);
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="child1">
        <div>       
            <div><label class="text1">First Label</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        <div>
            <div><label class="text2">Second Label</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child3">
        <div>
            <div><label class="text3">Third Label</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```